# How to send file in Android with Asmack+Openfire?

Tags: java, android, asmack

could you please send me the code to send file using Asmack + openfire.
I tried, but I am getting error like `error code="503" type="cancel`.
Please, help me.

Comment: i did all as you said, still its not working.

Comment: Ok check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721605/asmack-file-sending-error-503-type-cancel-with-openfire

Comment: You have to send a fully-qualified jabber ID in the "sentTo" it consists of a node, a domain, and a resource (user@domain/resource), what are you sending actually?.

Comment: Yes you are correct. now i am able to send a file. Thanks vzamanillo thanks a lot :)

Comment: But still getting problem while receiving a file in spark chat. I mean there was an error during file transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send a fully-qualified jabber ID as detination userID when you create the `OutgoingFileTransfer` it consists of a node, a domain, and a resource (user@domain/resource) as I said before in the comments, actually you are sending `a2@aaa` and is not correct.

```
<iq id="SU8c1-17" to="a2@aaa" from="a1@aaa/Smack" type="set">
    <si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si" id="jsi_2427513438410796738" profile="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer">
        <file xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer" name="user.json" size="379">
            <desc>test_file</desc>
        </file>
        <feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg">
            <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="form">
                <field var="stream-method" type="list-multi">
                    <option>
                        <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value>
                    </option>
                    <option>
                        <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value>
                    </option>
                </field>
            </x>
        </feature>
    </si>
</iq>
```

So, your sentTo variable shoulbe

```
String sentTo = "user@domain/resource";

OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(sentTo)
```

Comment: <iq type="error" id="U45Co-6" from="shailesh@apps-shailesh/Smack" to="admin@apps-shailesh/Smack"<error code="503" type="cancel"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>

Comment: I am getting this even putting valus

Answer (score -1):

I think you should send a jabber id with the file node, source and domain. It should be in sentTo method.